# What is the equivalent for bigint.pow(a) in Go?

Tags: go, pow, godoc

In my use case, I would like to know how the following Java code would be implemented in Go

```
BigInteger base = new BigInteger("16");
int exponent = 1;
BigInteger a = base.pow(exponent); //16^1 = 16
```

I am able to import the `math/big` package and create big integers, but not able to do `Pow()` function in Go. Also I don't find the function in the Go [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/).

Do I have to implement my own version of `Pow()` for bigint? Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`Exp`](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Exp) with `m` set to `nil`.

```
var i, e = big.NewInt(16), big.NewInt(2)
i.Exp(i, e, nil)
fmt.Println(i) // Prints 256
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/0QFbNHEsn5